# Why model could be fitted with numpy array in wrong dimensions in tensorflow(2.x)?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

When I learn to build a model with `tensorflow.keras.Model`(tensorflow.**version**=2.0.0), I compile my model on the way below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x,y)
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

When I need to use `model.fit` method, I make some attempts:

### Attempt 1:

```py
model.fit(
    x=[[1,1],[2,2]],
    y=[[1,1,1],[2,2,2]],
    epochs=3
)
```

It should be correct, and so the running result is.

### Attempt 2:

```py
model.fit(
    x=[[1,1],[2,2]],
    y=[[1,1],[2,2]],
    epochs=3
)
```

This code should thread an error since the dimensions of the y cannot adapt to the model's output, and I got a ValueError such as `Dimensions must be equal, but are 2 and 3 for 'loss/dense_loss/mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [?,2], [?,3]`. It is still as expect.

### Attempt 3:

```py
model.fit(
    x=[[1,1],[2,2]],
    y=[[1],[2]],
    epochs=3
)
```

So I think that this code should also thread an error just like `Attempt 2`, but why the model could be fitted with such a training data? and what did the model learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running your code from "Attempt 3" and do get an error using `tensorflow==2.1.0-rc1`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
x = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x,y)
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
model.fit(
    x=[[1,1],[2,2]],
    y=[[1],[2]],
    epochs=3
)
```

```
2.1.0-rc1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-ab313c8f2b57> in <module>()
     12     x=[[1,1],[2,2]],
     13     y=[[1,1],[2,2]],
---> 14     epochs=3
     15 )

7 frames
/tensorflow-2.1.0/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py in check_loss_and_target_compatibility(targets, loss_fns, output_shapes)
    808           raise ValueError('A target array with shape ' + str(y.shape) +
    809                            ' was passed for an output of shape ' + str(shape) +
--> 810                            ' while using as loss `' + loss_name + '`. '
    811                            'This loss expects targets to have the same shape '
    812                            'as the output.')

ValueError: A target array with shape (2, 2) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.
```

I'm surprised this would allow you to train in another tf2 version--it doesn't make sense for the model to have an output layer with different dimensions than your class. Can you clarify the output you get from your "Attempt 3" (maybe share a colab)?

Maybe this is due to your choice of loss function? `BinaryCrossentropy` should be used when there are only two label classes (assumed to be 0 and 1), which would typically be associated with a single output (e.g. `Dense(1)`). In other words, for each example, there should be a single floating-point value per prediction.

You might be able to get the model to compile and fit your data from your Attempt three if using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`:

```
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-4),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

As of right now, your loss doesn't seem to match your output dimensions.